# Why does Schema Registry send unwanted POST requests to create a topicName-key and topicName-value schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am adding two schemas to Schema registry using curl commands shown below (along with their coresponding responses)

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
--data '{"schema": "{\"namespace\":\"org.example\",\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"personKey\",\"version\":1,\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"personType\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8084/subjects/topicName-org.example.personKey/versions

{"id":1}                                              

schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:19:05,613] INFO 172.23.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2021:22:19:05 +0000] "POST /subjects/topicName-org.example.personKey/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 8  261 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)


curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
--data '{"schema": "{\"namespace\":\"org.example\",\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"personValue\",\"version\":1,\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"personName\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8084/subjects/topicName-org.example.personValue/versions

{"id":2}

schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:19:16,720] INFO 172.23.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2021:22:19:16 +0000] "POST /subjects/topicName-org.example.personValue/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 8  28 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
```

This seem fine so far.
I then send another curl command to kafka-rest-proxy to add a message to a topic using the newly created schema

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"key_schema_id":1, "value_schema_id":2,"records":[{"key":{"personType":"newPerson"}, "value":{"personName":"bob"}}]}' http://localhost:8082/topics/topicName

{"offsets":[{"partition":0,"offset":0,"error_code":null,"error":null}],"key_schema_id":1,"value_schema_id":2}
```

A `GET` request is made by Schema Registry to fetch the Schemas

```sh
schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:20:10,887] INFO 172.23.0.7 - - [19/Mar/2021:22:20:10 +0000] "GET /schemas/ids/1?fetchMaxId=false HTTP/1.1" 200 160  7 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:20:10,934] INFO 172.23.0.7 - - [19/Mar/2021:22:20:10 +0000] "GET /schemas/ids/2?fetchMaxId=false HTTP/1.1" 200 162  4 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:20:11,297] INFO Wait to catch up until the offset of the last message at 3 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:20:11,308] INFO 172.23.0.7 - - [19/Mar/2021:22:20:11 +0000] "POST /subjects/topicName-key/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 8  14 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:20:11,318] INFO Wait to catch up until the offset of the last message at 4 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
schema-registry                                | [2021-03-19 22:20:11,331] INFO 172.23.0.7 - - [19/Mar/2021:22:20:11 +0000] "POST /subjects/topicName-value/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 8  16 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
```

**What I am concerned with is why two `POST` requests are made to create schema entries for the key+value? This is uneeded for me as I want to use the TopicRecordNameStrategy.**

My docker-compose.yaml file:

```yaml
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.1.0
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8084/
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topicName:1:1"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    logging:
      driver: none

  kafka-rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.1.0
    hostname: kafka-rest-proxy
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082/
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafka-rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8084/
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=DEBUG,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=DEBUG,state.change.logger=DEBUG"
      KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KAFKA_TOOLS_LOG4J_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    logging:
      driver: none
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:8084/
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC: _schemas
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL: NONE
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're producing data to the topic, and the REST Proxy is using the default TopicNameStrategy as part of its serializer, causing the POST requests for key and value.

There's no correlation between providing the ids in the request and the Strategy that's used

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes sense. Is there a way to tell the REST Proxy which name strategy to use?

Comment: Not that I know of. There might be a way to set it server-wide using some `producer.[property]` value, however I'm not sure how that'd ultimately get parsed into any specific serializer object. I tried looking at the source code to see if it could be set at the request level, but didn't see anything like that